# Error en mi documento PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy teniendo un pequeño problema al tratar de insertar unos datos en mi base de datos, pero no he podido encontrar el respectivo error:

**ERROR**

> \n**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\mainApp\Create\registrarEmpresa.php:18\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\mainApp\Create\registrarEmpresa.php**
>   on line **18**
> \n

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```
<?php
  header("Context-type: application/json;");
  require '../conexion.php';
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  //Objeto convertido a formato UTF8 para insertar caracteres especiales en la BD del sistema
  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
  $nombreEmpresa    = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->nombre_empresa);
  $rutEmpresa       = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->rut_empresa);
  $direccionEmpresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->direccion_empresa);
  $giroEmpresa      = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->giro_empresa);
  $telefonoEmpresa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->telefono_empresa);
  $celularEmpresa   = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->celular_empresa);

  //Prepramos la consulta para INSERTAR datos en a BD a la tabla empresa
  $insertar_empresa = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO empresa(nombre_empresa, rut_empresa, direccion_empresa, giro_empresa, telefono_empresa, celular_empresa)
                                        VALUES (':nombreEmpresa', ':rutEmpresa', ':direccionEmpresa', ':giroEmpresa', ':telefonoEmpresa', ':celularEmpresa')");
  //Usamos el metodo bindParam() para captar las variables en la BD
  $insertar_empresa->bindParam(':nombreEmpresa', $nombreEmpresa);
  $insertar_empresa->bindParam(':rutEmpresa', $rutEmpresa);
  $insertar_empresa->bindParam(':direccionEmpresa', $direccionEmpresa);
  $insertar_empresa->bindParam(':giroEmpresa', $giroEmpresa);
  $insertar_empresa->bindParam(':telefonoEmpresa', $telefonoEmpresa);
  $insertar_empresa->bindParam(':celularEmpresa', $celularEmpresa);
  $insertar_empresa->execute();

  //Ejecutamos la consulta
  if ($insertar_empresa->execute())
  {
    $resultado = array('mensaje' => ''/*,'variable' => 0*/);
    $resultado['mensaje'] = "Se ha registrado correctamente la Empresa.";
    echo json_encode($resultado);
  }
  else
  {
    $resultado = array('mensaje' => ''/*,'variable' => 0*/);
    $resultado['mensaje'] = "Ha ocurrido un error: " . $mysqli->error;
    echo json_encode($resultado);
  }
 ?>
```

¡De antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Significa que la variable `$insertar_empresa` es `FALSE`, debido a error de sintaxis en la consulta, nombre de tabla o columna mal escrito o a que la conexión `$mysqli` es nula.

Comment: @A. Cedano Es verdad, acabo de actualizar mi nuevo error.

Comment: Tienes muchos errores más, te estoy corrigiendo el código, ahora posteo la respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios errores, los enumero aquí según he ido viendo y al final te propongo una solución:

- Esto no es un error, pero no necesitas usar `mysqli_real_escape_string` para las consultas preparadas. Precisamente las consultas preparadas se encargan de escapar cualquier dato tramposo. Puedes dejarlo si quieres, pero eso significa sobrecargar el código solamente y arriesgarte a que la función te modifique algún dato.
- En el insert tenías una columna de más, que era el ID de la empresa. Ese era el motivo principal del fallo inicial, pues la consulta era errónea.
- El método `bind_param` de mysqli no funciona como `bindParam` de PDO. Son dos API diferentes. **Primeramente** mysqli no admite marcadores de `:nombre`, sólo marcadores de posición `?`.  **Segundo** en el `bind_param` debes pasar entre comillas el tipo de dato de cada columna que participa en el `prepare`y luego el valor de cada columna mediante una variable.
- Estabas usando `execute` dos veces.
- Hacías un uso extraño del array que recoge la respuesta.
- Decías inocentemente que la empresa se agregó. No lo puedes decir sin verificar si hubo filas afectadas.
- Puedes hacer `echo` del array al final del todo, una sola vez.
- He puesto también un control sobre la conexión misma.
- ... no recuerdo si corregí algo más.

He aquí el código. Debería funcionar. Si da error, comenta:

```
<?php  
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  $resultado=array();
  if ($mysqli)
  {
      //Objeto convertido a formato UTF8 para insertar caracteres especiales en la BD del sistema
      $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
      $nombreEmpresa    = $data->nombre_empresa;
      $rutEmpresa       = $data->rut_empresa;
      $direccionEmpresa = $data->direccion_empresa;
      $giroEmpresa      = $data->giro_empresa;
      $telefonoEmpresa  = $data->telefono_empresa;
      $celularEmpresa   = $data->celular_empresa;

      //Prepramos la consulta para INSERTAR datos en a BD a la tabla empresa
      $sql="INSERT INTO empresa (
                                    nombre_empresa, 
                                    rut_empresa, 
                                    direccion_empresa, 
                                    giro_empresa, 
                                    telefono_empresa, 
                                    celular_empresa
                                )
                         VALUES (   ?, 
                                    ?, 
                                    ?, 
                                    ?, 
                                    ?, 
                                    ?
                                )";
      $insertar_empresa = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

      //Usamos el metodo bind_param() para captar las variables en la BD
      /*
          *Las 'ssssss' representan el tipo de dato, 
          *asumo que todas son varchar en la base de datos
          *si alguno es numérico, debes poner una i en su posición
      */
      $insertar_empresa->bind_param('ssssss', $nombreEmpresa,$rutEmpresa,$direccionEmpresa,$giroEmpresa,$telefonoEmpresa,$celularEmpresa);

      //Ejecutamos la consulta
      if ($insertar_empresa->execute())
      {
        /*
           *Verificamos si hubo filas afectadas
           *y decidimos el estado del mensaje con un operador ternario
        */
        $insertedRows=$insertar_empresa->affected_rows;  
        $mensaje=($insertedRows > 0) ? "Se ha registrado correctamente la Empresa." : "No fue posible la inserción. Error: ".$insertar_empresa->error;  
        $resultado['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
      }
      else
      {
        $resultado['mensaje'] = "Ha ocurrido un error: " . $mysqli->error;
      }

    }
    else
    {    
        $resultado['mensaje'] = "No hay conexión a la BD";
    }

    echo json_encode($resultado);

 ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución brindada, ha funcionado muy bien y sobre todo por cada enumeración de error (ayuda a entender más el error cometido y de su por qué).